# Measurement of small signal voltage of switched capacitor dc-dc converter

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit, switch-mode-power-supply

I have a short question. I have a Switched capacitor dc-dc converter which I want to obtain the magnitude bodeplot in dB manually rather than using AC_analysis in the simulation (To understand how to do it with hand in simulation). I have done the following:

1. The input of the dc-dc converter consists of a dc-source (4 V) and a sine wave source applying a small signal with frequency of 48.6 kHz and a small signal amplitude of 100 mV
2. Transient response has been conducted
3. Output voltage is 1.1 V with a small signal that a ripple, caused by the switching of the dc-dc converter, is superimposed on that small signal.

The result in step 3 is shown below:
[image]

If you want to measure the output small signal, on Vout = 1.1 V, do you measure the peak-to-peak including the ripple, or do I need to remove that ripple first before measuring the output small signal and then using 20*log(Vout,small/Vin,small)?

Comment: Would a low pass filter designed to remove just the high frequency ripple be appropriate before attempting measurement?

Comment: If it is only for measurement, then I could do, but in practice, a load will be connected. But I am not sure if I need to measure the ripple peak to peak as my small signal or first remove ripple first.

Comment: I don't really understand the purpose for the calculation and how important certain details may be. So can't really offer much of use, I fear.

Comment: There was a situation I can't use AC-analysis in cadence virtuoso because the modelled behaviour of VCO in verilog AMS was not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to remove the ripple, it will change Voltage peak to peak calcs. You could use a median filter or turn up filtering (low pass) on the scope or low pass the data

Comment: Is there a fundamental reason why ripple MUST be removed or is it just that an AC-analysis in a simulator also do?

Comment: How are you calculating Vpk?

Comment: I thought measuring the Vpk at the peak of the small signal and the bottom of the small signal with ripple.